# Conditions added to a first order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, characteristics, linear-pde

Given this PDE

$$xu_x + yu_y + zu_z=0$$

It is asked, in some old paper-and-pencil notes I am reading, to solve it.

1) Firstly, finding the general solution

2) Then, finding the particular solution under the condition $u(1,y,z)=3yz$

3) Then, finding (again from scratch) the particular solution under the condition $u(1,y,1)=y^2$

Now, the first point is simple, because I've used the characteristics method, finding

$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{z}$$

so, the system

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}\\
\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{z}
\end{cases}
$$

leads to

$$
\begin{cases}
\zeta_1:=\pm e^{K_1}=\frac{x}{y}\\
\zeta_2:=\pm e^{K_2}=\frac{y}{z}
\end{cases}
$$

so

$$
u(x,y,z)=\Phi(\zeta_1,\zeta_2)=\Phi\left(\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z}\right)
$$

solution that I've just verified by chain rule.

But, what about the second point?

I've tried to solve like this:

$$3yz=u(1,y,z)=\Phi\left(\frac{1}{y},\frac{y}{z}\right)$$

$$\zeta_1=\frac{1}{y} \rightarrow 3 y^2 z\zeta_1=3yz$$

$$\zeta_2=\frac{y}{z} \rightarrow 3 z^2 \zeta_2=3yz$$

obtaining something that I am not able to recombine.

Can anyone help me to see if the passages here are right and how to complete?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For the second question:

$$u = \Phi(x/y,y/z)=F(y/x,z/y)$$

Now use the $u(1,y,z)=F(y,z/y)=3yz$

Use the substitution $v=z/y \implies z = vy \implies F(y,v)=3y^2v$

Hence, we obtain $u=3(y/x)^2(z/y)=3yz/x^2.$

**Edit:** The goal is to transform the function such that it is $F(a,b)$.

Let us have a look at the second part of the question. We know that 
$$u(x,y,z)=\Phi(x/y,y/z)=F(y/x,y/z)$$

I inverted the first argument such that the variables that we will fix are now in the denominator. Using $u(1,y,1)=y^2$ we obtain:

$$u(1,y,1)=F(y,y)=y^2=y\cdot y.$$

Hence, the function $F(\alpha, \beta)$ just multiplies is arguments and we obtain:

$$u(x,y,z)=F(y/x,y/z)=\frac{y^2}{xz}.$$

Comment: :) Enlightening! Thanks for hint, all clear, but I'd like to know:
- Can you explain what is the idea, the mental criterion that I have to adopt to arrive at the subtitution you used? Is it a standard substitution or else how do I arrive to this?

Comment: Up to now, I haven't understood how are the criteria to sketch a suitable substitution for any condition proposed.
I noticed I can reach the same result without inventing any substitution, but I just dragged the problem in another place. Let me show the passages:
$$u(1,y,z)=\Phi(\frac{1}{y},\frac{y}{z})=3yz$$
I replaced $\frac{1}{y}$ with $\frac{x}{y}$, obtaining
$$u(x,y,z)=\Phi(\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z})=3\frac{y}{x}z$$
At this point, I reach the solution multiplying by $\frac{y}{y}$
$$u(x,y,z)=\Phi(\frac{x}{y},\frac{y}{z})=3\frac{y}{x}\frac{z}{y}y$$
I don't understand how to do...

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I added an edit to my answer. Maybe the second example might help you in getting a better picture how to solve these problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) according to what I'm understanding, if I have a function F in N arguments, I have to manipulate the function (the "known term") on the right member in order to obtain N "pieces" that are suitable to be transformed in the arguments of F! Then I verify if the solution satisfies the PDE, otherwise I retry! Am I right? :)

Comment: Yes, actually that is a little bit of playing around, but it is quicker than using the parametrization method.

Comment: I do owe you! :) I'll search for information about parametrization method. The more deterministic becomes the solution sketching, the better is for me.